# How do i display this data on my HTML it comes back as being undefined on my table

Tags: javascript

```
fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=Bitcoin%2Cdai%2Csolana&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true")

    .then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     return data.json();
})

    .then((completeData) => {
    console.log(completeData)

    if(completeData.length > 0) {
        var cryptoCoin = ""
    }

    for (var i=0; i = completeData.length; i++) {
    completeData.forEach(completeData[i]) 
        cryptoCoin += "<tr>"
        cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData.bitcoin} </td>`;
        cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData.usd_market_cap} </td>`;
        cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData.usd_24h_vol} </td>`;
        cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData.usd} </td>`;
    }
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = cryptoCoin;
})
   .catch ((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

How would i display this to my HTML it comes back on my HTML as undefined what am i missing. I'm new to javascript so trying to understand.

Comment: Complete code would be useful in order to be able to replicate your issue and offer a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code. i fixed that it would be work and you see that it push strings in your table. the rest is homework for you ;-)

```js
fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=Bitcoin%2Cdai%2Csolana&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true")
.then((data) => {     
     return data.json();
})

    .then((completeData) => {    
    
      let table = document.querySelector('table');
      let keys = Object.keys(completeData)
      console.log(keys)
      for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let usd = completeData[keys[i]].usd;      
        let usd_market_cap = completeData[keys[i]].usd_market_cap
        let usd_24h_vol = completeData[keys[i]].usd_24h_vol
        let row = `<td> ${usd} </td> <td> ${usd_market_cap} </td> <td> ${usd_24h_vol} </td>`;

        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = row
        table.appendChild(tr)
    }

})
   .catch ((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

```html
<table border="1" id="data">
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
</table>
```

Comment: That code deff displayed the info on the page just need to fix it and make it look pretty now thank you so much!!! And you're right the rest is for sure homework for me!

Comment: @IrvensDupuy You welcome! Thank you very much for you feedback. :-)

Comment: @IrvensDupuy I updated the code a little bit. so you have the table view...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

First of all, you declare the cryptoCoin variable inside the if and then when the if bracket closes you start your for loop. You should have the declaration of the variable within the same scope or higher one like below.

Second, you should not use both the for loop and the forEach which you are currently using in a completely wrong way.

Third, *i* should be less than the *completeData.length* not equal.

Finally, you should probably close the table row.

Should look more like this:

```
if (completeData.length > 0) {
    var cryptoCoin = "";
    for (var i=0; i < completeData.length; i++) {
      cryptoCoin += "<tr>";
      cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData[i].bitcoin} </td>`;
      cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData[i].usd_market_cap} </td>`;
      cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData[i].usd_24h_vol} </td>`;
      cryptoCoin += `<td> ${completeData[i].usd} </td>`; 
      cryptoCoin += "</tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = cryptoCoin;
  }
```

Comment: Thank You  so much for the feedback. Changed the code around for sure but its data is still not showing up on the page.